# How to use autentication with roles on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question for all the ASP.NET veterans, I'm currently working on a project involving displaying different pages to users with different roles.
For example, Admin Can add new users to the website
Role-x users can edit the database A
Role-y users can edit database A & B
Role-Z users can access views of database B
so my question is how can I implement this (serving different pages to different users based on their credentials(Roles)).
I just need a little guide to what I have to implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dou you mean validations on bd level? or like Authorization Filter

Comment: Hello Maruf, I think your question is not to the point. Making role based authentication in asp.net is difficult to answer with some simple code snippets. It has its own procedures. please refer blogs out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can found some good tutorials about authentication and authorization, please check it :

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

[A better way to handle authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/a-better-way-to-handle-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

and here some more simple approach:

[Role Based Authentication In ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/role-based-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc/)

If your question is more about Database please add the corresponding Tag.

Edit:

Here one more link that I highly suggest you, it explain step by step how to implement very clearly, there is example (4 tutorials) from Authentication and Authorization in MVC until Role-Based :

[Authentication and Authorization in MVC](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/authentication-and-authorization-in-mvc/)

Comment: the Role based approach was what I was looking for thanks.